# Recommended AWS storage type for Cassandra?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cassandra, datastax

I need to deploy Cassandra on AWS but am confused as to what type of [AWS storage](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Storage.html) is most suitable for Cassandra.

The Datastax documentation here:

http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/planning/planPlanningEC2.html

says that EBS volumes are recommended. At the same time the Datastax AMI documentation:

http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/install/installAMI.html

says that:

- Uses RAID0 ephemeral disks for data storage and commit logs.
- Launches EBS-backed instances for faster start-up, not database
  storage.

So which one is the recommended storage type for Cassandra? The [EBS storage](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AmazonEBS.html) or the [Instance storage](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many of the new eC2 instances are EBS only (http://www.ec2instances.info/) I am not sure when the cassandra document was written but EBS disk have improved a lot recently and amazon launches new type frequently, so you will be able to find what you're looking for with one of the type

You can check https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSVolumeTypes.html?icmpid=docs_ec2_console and its recommended `Provisioned IOPS SSD (io1)`

To add a reason why AWS is moving to EBS and why it would be good for cassandra data is because of *ephemeral* type of data, you might not want your data to disappear if your instance is terminated (because of a crash or a stop you made) at least when your instance is gone, you still have access to your data and can attach the EBS volume to a new instance (really useful also when up/down-grading instances)

Comment: This is exactly why I would prefer EBS, because the data is not lost when your instance is switched off. But at the same time having no experience with AWS I am hesitant about the performance of Cassandra running on EBS.

Comment: I would rely on the AWS documentation as I know they updated when st1 and sc1 were launched - EBS are SSD drive so good performance and io1 you can provision up to 30 IOPS per GiB so should be more than enough

Answer (score 0):

I came upon this presentation, which clearly answers the question with a very interesting use case:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1R-mgOcOSd4

To summarize:

1. EBS has changed a lot since 2011 when major companies like Netflix
   had problems with it.
2. EBS and GP2 are now the recommended storage
   for Cassandra and you should not expect any bottlenecks there.
3. Datastax have recently updated their documentation to also recommend
   EBS:

   http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/planning/planPlanningEC2.html

Answer (score 0):

No doubt EBS,

Memory optimized boxes are best suited for cassandra

**T2**
T2 are Burstable Performance Instances that offer a baseline level of CPU performance with the capability to burst above the baseline

**M4**
M4 instances are the most recent general-purpose instances. The M4 family of instances offers a balance of memory, network, and compute resources, and it is a better option for several applications

**C4**
These instances are recent additions to the compute-optimized instances that feature maximum performance processors with the lowest compute/price performance in EC2 Instance types.

**X1**
These instances are best suited for enterprise-class, large-scale, in-memory applications and offer the lowest price for each GiB of RAM among AWS EC2 instance types. The X1 instances are the latest addition to the EC2 memory-optimized instance group and are intended for executing high-scale, in-memory databases and in-memory applications over the AWS cloud.

for pricing and other information 
https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/